# How can I change color of Page Title font in Kleanity WordPress theme

Tags: css, wordpress

How can I change the color of Page Title font in Kleanity WordPress theme? I've looked everywhere but cannot see how.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to go in Appearance -> Customize -> Color and there you will find details.

Or you can go to Goodlayers and update the skin settings.

You can find more details here: http://demo.goodlayers.com/document/kleanity/

It is always good to read the documentation.

**Edit 1**: If neither of the 2 options above work, you can go to Appearance -> Customize -> Miscellaneous and put the a CSS rule to match the page title you wish to change

Comment: I found it's on the page. I should have guessed.